# List of all authors on site in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll, author

I'm currently using a data file to specify authors on a site, and I need to pull the list of all of them onto an About page.

Here's the format of my `_data/authors.yml` file

```
# Authors
one:
  name: One
  display_name: Person One
  avatar: /img/avatar1.jpg
  permalink: author/personone/
two:
  name: Two
  display_name: Person Two
  avatar: /img/avatar2.jpg
  permalink: author/persontwo/
```

I would use this if it were a category page, to list the person for their specified posts:

```
{% for post in site.categories.[page.category] %}
{% assign author = site.data.authors[post.author] %}
    {{ author.display_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I want to show ALL authors, and not have to specify a post that they're related to (some authors have no posts on the site yet).

Ideas?

Edit:

Swapped my code from that Jekyll docs example to:

```
<ul>
    {% for author in site.data.authors %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ author.permalink }}">
                {{ author.display_name }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Showing nothing after rebuilding...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the right YML structure.

in `_data/authors.yml`:

```
- name: One
  display_name: Person One
  avatar: /img/avatar1.jpg
  permalink: author/personone/

- name: Two
  display_name: Person Two
  avatar: /img/avatar2.jpg
  permalink: author/persontwo/
```

(note the dashes)

Then:

```
<ul>
    {% for author in site.data.authors %}
    <li>
        {{ author.display_name }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**In addition**  in case you wanted to keep the original YAML structure.
You could use this to access the authors (use an index of 1).

```
<ul>
    {% for author in site.data.authors %}
    <li>
        {{ author[1].name }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm just trying to show all authors on the site, with a link to their profile page. I don't want to pull in any posts/data, just what's already specified (full name, avatar, page URL) from the `authors.yml`. I'm sure that there's a syntax that I'm missing to be able to make it work.

Comment: Oh. Well that's [pretty easy](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/#example-list-of-members).

Comment: Tried that already. I think that the format of my `authors.yml` file may be different that Jekyll docs show, so the syntax isn't working. I tried what was in their examples in every way I could think of already to no avail.

Comment: Edited my response above with new code based on the Jekyll docs. Still not working.

Comment: Edited my answer, because I apparently didn't understand the question.

Comment: Take a look at Jekyll's [Accessing a specific author](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/#example-accessing-a-specific-author) section. That's how the yml file is structured to pull author specific info elsewhere on the site. While your code works if I change the yml format, it breaks all of the other references to authors on the site. I need to target each author using the yml layout on this example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, [as suggested here](https://gist.github.com/ravasthi/1834570#gistcomment-1584590):

In _config.yml:

```
authors:
  hanzou:
    name: Hanzou Hattori
    display_name: Hanzou
    gravatar: c66919cb194f96c696c1da0c47354a6a
    email: hanzou@company.com
    web: http://company.com
    twitter: company
    github: hhattori
  jorgen:
    name: Jörgen Mortensen
    display_name: Jörgen
    gravatar: 12e480a364a5c19214f99b4dfe9a11d5
    email: jorgen@company.com
    web: http://company.com
    twitter: company
    github: jorgenm
```

Listing authors in a template:

```
{% for author in site.authors %}
    {{ author[1].name }} -- {{ author[1].email }}
{% endfor %}
```